# IE 10 issue - "next page" on a website and SAP Punchout instance

Tags: html, ssl, browser, internet-explorer-10, netweaver

I'm responsible for a e-procurement team that integrates with a number of large customer ERPs.  Before you duck out if you're not an ERP expert, please note that this may be more of a browser issue/question for resolution than a SAP question.

One of our customers has been standardized on IE8 for punching out to our catalog ( yes, I know, IE8 :).  SAP isn't exactly setting the curve for e-technology).   They want to move to IE10, but we're having really bizarre issues during the testing phase.  As a prereq, please note that the way this solution works is that they start their session inside SAP, punchout to our e-catalog, but the site retains a "frameset" (a traditional frameset...not iframes/ajax div etc) with the top frame being a way to return to the SAP system, and the bottom frame being the catalog.  The bottom frame is encoded and we don't really have any way to know if its manipulating our catalog code, or what.

---

**ISSUE:**

In IE8, there are no issues with the system.  They use our shopping cart, add things to the cart, go to the review cart on the next page, and punch the data back into SAP.

In IE10, it blank screens on the second page, almost like a custom SAP 404 error - just completely blank... when you view source, it IS a

> 404 "this page cannot be displayed"

but the URL that is given is for the internal SAP system, rather than our catalog (which it SHOULD be trying to look for a page on our catalog rather than an internal SAP page.  So it's more or less like it doesn't like something on our catalo page, environment, whatever...and then redirects to a internal SAP page that doesn't exist/isn't working correctly).  Every time anything is clicked on the page (form submission, link, etc) that has to refresh the entire page/frame, the system white screens.  We are using iframes (yes, I know :) .  Ajax issues with IE8 was the driver there, IE8 was a requirement for our customer due to SAP...) to submit certain datapoints on the page, and we don't have any problem submitting to the iframe.  The second you submit to the whole page, white screen/404 issue.

**FACTORS:**

- It works fine in IE8.  It also works perfectly in IE10 OUTSIDE of the frameset SAP is generating.  Even inside of the customers secure environment.  The second SAP gets involved, the issue occurs.  We've never seen this issue with any other deployment of anything, anywhere.
- SSL:  We managed to get the testers to get past the first page by turning off SSL, but they had to work their way outside of the traditional security in SAP as well so I'm not sure if this has any relevance at all.  But SSL compatibility with SAP or frameset as it pertains to IE10 was a thought process.
- It doesn't seem to be a form submission issue.  We initially thought it might have something to do with the way IE10 interprets frame ID as we were submitting to _self, etc., but turns out traditional links don't work either with no sort of target information.
- It's definitely on the page load itself, not on the submission of form data to the page, when the white screen happens.  We noticed that half of the page would load for a split second before it white screened.  Initially we thought it was based on something that was being sent, but its definitely past any header submissions or form posts.
- We pretty much broke apart the entirety of the code and weeded out all kinds of factors and tested them independently and in different combinations...so extensively that I'm almost positive it isn't a traditional coding issue. The result pages ("second page") we set for the tests had almost no content at all.  We could not find any true consistent patterns.  Sometimes the user could make it to the second page, other times not (only on the tests, never on the actual catalog), but usually it was the same for all test scenarios (so if we had 9 test scenarios, they'd all fail, or they'd all succeed).

**Conclusions thus far:**

- We're almost positive it isn't code related. However, it could absolutely be caching related?  Although we have the user clearing caching almost every page test, I'm not sure if that clears everything like page load over SSL or something of that nature?
- Clearly there is some major difference between IE10 and IE8 and how they interpret the same environment.  This might just be a SAP issue, but at the same time, there are other punchout environments that work with IE10 and SAP.  Could it be our SSL type?  What is interpreted differently in those scenarios between the two browsers?
- Is there any code I can implement on the page to evaluate what's going on at client side and store down to the server for review?  The SAP system is pretty security intensive, as is the team that is helping us test this.  We don't really have the option to deploy anything too advanced on the users computer that's testing these scenarios, and we can only gather so much from implementing code that does tickcounts and watches for function execution on the server because I'm almost positive this is browser side (if it works in IE10, but then fails in this wrapper with IE10, there has to be some sort of manipulation there I need to be able to track.  Any way to do that via code?)

Anything else you can think of would be greatly helpful.  We've been testing for countless hours....we have a pretty technically advanced team...really can't catch a break on this one or find any consistencies.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know what version of SAP Netweaver you're running?

Comment: and which SAP software is it? (we'll never know...)